# How to store my delegate instance in Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, lua

C stuff, getting a bit lost with it having coming from LUA. I've programmed for years but not sure how to store my delegate object and point to it later. I'm able to create a new instances fine but need to reference a previously created instance from a Corona Enterprise plugin for iOS. Hopefully someone can help past this small issue.

So I define a variable after my CoronaIbeaconDelegate @interface like so:

```
CoronaIBeaconDelegate *coronaIBeaconDelegate;
```

Later on in my Corona Plugin class code I create a instance of CoronaIBeaconDelegate like so:

```
int
PluginLibrary::scan( lua_State *L )
{

int listenerIndex = 1;
coronaIBeaconDelegate = [[CoronaIBeaconDelegate alloc] firstRegion];

if ( CoronaLuaIsListener( L, listenerIndex, kEvent ) )
{

    Self *library = ToLibrary( L );

    CoronaLuaRef listener = CoronaLuaNewRef( L, listenerIndex );
    library->Initialize( listener );


    // Create event and add message to it
    CoronaLuaNewEvent( L, kEvent );

    lua_pushstring(L,"scan");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "phase" );

    lua_pushboolean(L,true );
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "scanning" );

    lua_pushstring( L, "Scanning Started" );
    lua_setfield( L, -2, "message" );
    // Dispatch event to library's listener
    CoronaLuaDispatchEvent( L, library->GetListener(), 0 );

}

return 0;

}
```

This will work fine but I get a warning when storing the delegate in coronaIBeaconDelegate variable saying "instance method not found -firstRegion" but this will call the class function firstRegion fine as expected and my IBeacon code starts scanning.

What I want to do is be able to call another function in the CoronaIBeaconDelegate class called stopRangingForBeacons likes so using the previous instance:

```
int
PluginLibrary::stopscan( lua_State *L )
{
int listenerIndex = 1;
[coronaIBeaconDelegate stopRangingForBeacons];

if ( CoronaLuaIsListener( L, listenerIndex, kEvent ) )
{

    Self *library = ToLibrary( L );

    CoronaLuaRef listener = CoronaLuaNewRef( L, listenerIndex );
    library->Initialize( listener );


    // Create event and add message to it
    CoronaLuaNewEvent( L, kEvent );

    lua_pushstring(L,"stopscan");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "phase" );

    lua_pushboolean(L,true );
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "scanning" );

    lua_pushstring( L, "Scanning Stopped" );
    lua_setfield( L, -2, "message" );
    // Dispatch event to library's listener
    CoronaLuaDispatchEvent( L, library->GetListener(), 0 );

 }

 return 0;
}
```

Whats occurs is a null error. I tried to store the previous instance in the coronaIBeacon variable but it doesn't work. I really can't seem to suss this simple task.

Please help thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per usual I answer my own question. My issue was due to the way I was initialising my instance. Here is the correct way in my case.

```
 IBeaconDelegate = [[CoronaIBeaconDelegate alloc] init];
[IBeaconDelegate firstRegion];
```